# Get python unittest current test name

Tags: python, unit-testing

How do I get the current unittest name and print it on the terminal?

I tried the below code. I did not get error message but also cannot see it on the terminal.

```
import unittest
import logging
import pandas as pd

class TestPass():
    def is_pass(self, source, target):
        logging.info(f'Currently running: {unittest.TestCase.id}')
        if (source - target == 0).bool():
           return True
        else:
           return False

class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def dummy_fail(self):
        df1 = pd.DataFrame({'number': ['2']})
        df2 = pd.DataFrame({'number': ['1']})
        assert(test.is_pass(df1, df2))

test = TestPass()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Arguably, that kind of log message should be produced by the test runner, not the test itself.

Comment: Why do you event need that ?
If you can just run the tests in the verbose mode, which will show you separtaed output for every method instead for every class just set the `verbosity=2` and you will get similar output like there
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change method arguments to:

```
def is_pass(self, test, source, target):
.
.
assert(test.is_pass(self, df1, df2))
```

Then, try adding:

```
   print(test._testMethodName)
```

And use method name as test name.

Also, 'dummy_fail(self):' method is not defined by unittest as test method.
Change it to be with test prefix: def test_dummy_fail(self)